# Javascript: How to delete specific character values within strings within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I am trying to remove punctuation from each string within an array, but this problem would exist for trying to delete any type of character within strings within an array.

I have attempted to create 3 loops:
The first loop iterates over each item in arrayA that I'm aiming to edit. 
The second loop iterates through each character in each string in arrayA. 
The third loop checks whether the character in arrayA matches any character in arrayB, and deletes it if it does.

Nothing is being deleted however, and I'm not sure why.

This is my code so far:

```
let arrayA = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
let arrayB = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

arrayA.forEach((item) => {
    for (let i=0; i < item.length; i++) {
        for (let arrayBIndex = 0; arrayBIndex < arrayB.length; arrayBIndex++) {
            item.replace(arrayB[arrayBIndex], '');
        };
    };
});
console.log(arrayA);
```

I have searched for other questions dealing with this, but I haven't been able to find any answers, specifically where the elements to delete are contained in another list. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `String.replace` does not modify the original string. You should use the return value of the function instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate regular expression using `arrayB` and then using `array#map` iterate through each word in `arrayA` and use `string#replace` to get rid of words from `arrayB`.

```js
let arrayA = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'],
    arrayB = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'],
    regExp = new RegExp(arrayB.join('|'), 'g'),
    result = arrayA.map(word => word.replace(regExp, ''));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped a lot. Just as a clarification for anyone using this with punctuation specifically. I discovered that punctuation as strings cannot necessarily be indicated using just apostrophes in this solution, as the fullstop ('.') matches any character. For removing punctuation, arrayB = [',', '\\.', '"', '\'', '!', '-'] as this prevents the fullstop and the apostrophe from behaving unexpectedly with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to follow with arrays, I would suggest to transform your strings into an array of characters and using array filter operator.

However you can probably achieve what you want to do with regular expressions

```js
    const arrayA = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
    const arrayB = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    const result = arrayA
                      .map(s => [...s]) // array of chars
                      .map(chars => chars.filter(ch=>!arrayB.includes(ch)).join(''))//filter out invalid char and transform back into string

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `arrayA.map(item => [...item].filter(char => !arrayB.includes(char)).join(""))` <- thats less ugly

Comment: that is just a matter of preference. Actually putting the "join" (from the snippet of my answer) in its own map would be even better in my opinion (easier to see the "algorithm" -> map(toChar).filter(invalidChar).map(toString)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.splice()`, take a look on this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score -1):

```
 const result = arrayA.map(item => {
   let replaced = "";
   for(const char of item)
     if(!arrayB.includes(char)) 
        replaced += char;
   return replaced;
});
```

Strings are immutable. Every mutation returns a new string instead of mutating the original.